# How to query this is MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Matches

```
ID| radiant_name | dire_name | radiant_win
1 |          LV  |       LGD | true 
2 |         LGD  |        LV | false
3 |          LV  |       LGD | false
4 |          LV  |       LGD | false
5 |         LGD  |        LV | false
```

**Desired OUTPUT :D :**

**ex.**

```
Team "LV" wins 3.
Team "LGD" wins 2.
```

**I Have tried:**

Using Group by and SUM but the results is different.

**ex. query:**

```
SELECT SUM(IF(radiant_win = 1? 1, 0)) as LV, SUM(IF(radiant_win = 1? 0,1)) as LGD
```

**ex. not desired results ~_~ :**

```
Team "LV" wins 1.
Team "LGD" wins 4.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, if wins per radiant team are needed:

```
SELECT radiant_team_id, count(*) FROM yourtable GROUP BY radiant_team_id HAVING radiant_win = 'true';
```

Or if you need wins per radiant teams, and wins per dire team too then you might wanna use UNIONS but i don't see why would you want that since you can find using above query.

Comment: its not working ~_~ . i want to see the wins sum of each team and determine who is the winner

Comment: Unknown column 'radiant_win' in 'having clause'

Comment: make sure you have column named `radiant_win` as you have mentioned in your question, check spelling, also you have changed your question by changing columns in the table, you have to stick to one question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(radiant_team_id), radiant_team_id 
FROM yourtablename
WHERE radiant_win='true'
```